# Como fazer para que quando um pessoa copiar algo do meu site, vá junto para a área de transferência "fonte: meusite.com"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu gostaria de fazer que quando alguma pessoa copiar algo do meu site, automaticamente seja adicionado ao conteúdo copiado a fonte, por exemplo:

> fonte: meusite.com

Comment: http://www.scriptbrasil.com.br/forum/topic/113753-copiar-para-area-de-transferencia/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o código abaixo (retirado [deste tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17175735/add-extra-info-copyright-notice-read-more-link-to-copied-text-and-preserve-for)):

```js
function addLink() {
        var body_element = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        var pagelink = '\n\nMai multe Bancuri pe: http://bancuricubarbatisifemei.blogspot.com/\n'; 
        var copytext = selection + pagelink;
        var newdiv = document.createElement('pre');
        newdiv.style.position = 'absolute';
        newdiv.style.left = '-99999px';
        body_element.appendChild(newdiv);
        newdiv.innerHTML = copytext;
        selection.selectAllChildren(newdiv);
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            body_element.removeChild(newdiv);
        }, 0);
    }

document.oncopy = addLink;
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WwE7V/1/)

Nota: Não funciona no Internet Explorer!

Comment: Tem que funcionar no IE também!